# How to set footer parallax effect on mobile device like desktop?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have background image and footer with parallax effect which is working perfectly on the desktop but It is not working on the mobile device. I am not able to scroll the background image to display the footer. I need to scroll the image to check the footer like desktop. Would you help me in this?

**CSS**

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

    #content {
        background-image: url('http://7606-presscdn-0-74.pagely.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Dubai-Photos-Images-Travel-Tourist-Images-Pictures-800x600.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto !important;
        background-position: center;
        min-height: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 180px;
        z-index: 1;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;

    }

    #footer {
        position:fixed;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        height:200px;
        z-index:-1;
        background-color:#000;
        color: #fff;

    }   

.column-left{ float: left; width: 33%; }
.column-right{ float: right; width: 33%; }
.column-center{ display: inline-block; width: 33%; }
.column-left, .column-right, .column-center
{
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
</div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p class="column-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>

        <p class="column-right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

        <p class="column-center" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

    </div>
```

Comment: Your code just includes footer section add remaining codes.

Comment: I forgot to add one div. I added now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `height`, I couldn't find above codes even working `large resolution`, so by declaring height for `#content` it work.

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#content {
        background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1600x1600');
        background-size: cover;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-position: center;
        margin-bottom: 180px;
        z-index: 1;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    #footer {
        position:fixed;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        height:200px;
        z-index:-1;
        background-color:#000;
        color: #fff;
    }   

.column-left{ float: left; width: 33%; }
.column-right{ float: right; width: 33%; }
.column-center{ display: inline-block; width: 33%; }
.column-left, .column-right, .column-center
{
    margin-top: 30px;
}
@media screen and (max-width:640px){
    #content{
        height: 100vh;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
<div id="footer">
    <p class="column-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>

    <p class="column-right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

    <p class="column-center" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mr.frnt, It is not working on mobile. I am not able to scroll the background image

Comment: @NarendraVerma can you create a jsFiddle. Check this jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bpzxva4r/ it works fine.

Comment: Sorry for delay reply Mr.frnt. It is working for me. Thanks for your help.Upvote from my side

Comment: Welcome @NarendraVerma :-)